# What is the generator of all polynomials that determine the zero function in a finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $F$ be any finite field.  The set of all $a(x)\in F[x]$ which determine the zero function is an ideal of $F[x]$.

> What is its generator?

Let $c_0,\cdots,c_n$ be the elements of $F$.  I think $g(x)=(x-c_0)\cdots(x-c_n)$ is the generator, as it's the common factor of all polynomials which determine the zero function in $F[x]$.  Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. A generator $g$ has to be a multiple of $x-c$ for every element $c \in F$ as you can see by considering the Euclidean division of $g$ by $x-c$. We get the conclusion as $x-c_1,x-c_2$ are coprime polynomials for $c_1 \neq c_2$.